# how to show future dates in calendar in swift3

Tags: ios, swift

I am using DaySquare calendar.

I have dateObjects array.

I have to show this dates in calendar but I am getting reason: 'Invalid month: 0' error.

```
import UIKit
import Daysquare

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var dateObjects = [Date]()
    var calendarFromDateArr2 = [String]()

    @IBOutlet var calendarView: DAYCalendarView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        calendarFromDateArr2 =  ["2017-10-30T07:41:00", "2017-10-30T11:23:00", "2017-10-30T11:48:00", "2017-11-10T00:00:00", "2017-11-13T19:43:00", "2017-12-01T00:00:00", "2017-12-31T00:00:00"]

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        dateObjects = calendarFromDateArr2.flatMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0) }

        print(dateObjects)

        for date in dateObjects
        {
            self.calendarView.selectedDate = date
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting single value when I give "return" after this line:

```
self.calendarView.selectedDate = date.
```

Comment: An error in the `DaySquare` calendar? Note that `setSelectedDate` is always animated, there is a delay before the component is updated correctly, therefore it's not probably a good idea to call `selectedDate =` in a loop. It also makes little sense...

Comment: Note that `DaySquare` does not support multiple selection.